# Why is my script to search google not working?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I created a python script to search google and the prompts are working, but I'm getting no results no matter what I type. Below is the python script it supposed to prompt you for your search and ask how many results you want and spit it out into a .csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_google_search_results_urls(query, num_results=10):
base_url = "https://www.google.com/search"
params = {"q": query, "num": num_results}

response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
result_urls = []

for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
    link = result.select_one("a")
    if link and link["href"].startswith("http"):
        result_urls.append(link["href"])

return result_urls

def write_urls_to_csv(urls, csv_file):
with open(csv_file, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(["URL"])

    for url in urls:
        csv_writer.writerow([url])

if __name__ == "__main__":
search_query = input("Enter your Google search query: ")
num_results = int(input("Enter the number of search results to fetch: "))

search_results = get_google_search_results_urls(search_query, num_results)

if search_results:
    csv_file_name = "google_search_results.csv"
    write_urls_to_csv(search_results, csv_file_name)
    print(f"Search results URLs written to {csv_file_name}")
else:
    print("No search results found.")
```

Comment: Could you indent the code in your question properly?

Comment: Your `base_url = "https://www.bing.com"`  not  `base_url = "https://www.google.com"` maybe you should switch it to the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `get_google_search_results_urls()`

```
    base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?"
    params = {"q": query, "num": num_results}


    BROWSER_HEADER = {
        "Accept-Language": "en-US",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    response = requests.get(url=base_url, params=params, headers=BROWSER_HEADER)
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Also in `if __name__ == "__main__"` you have to change the if condition if you want to check wether the `search_results` is empty or not:

```
    if len(search_results) != 0:
```

I passed the `"Accept-Language"` and `"User-Agent"` into http header.

To find your own `User-Agent`(assuming your browser is chrome):

- Go to address bar
- Enter `chrome://version/`

Answer (score 0):

Your `base_url` is for Bing while the `tF2Cxc` class in your Soup `select` is specific to Google. Also note that there can be `https` as well as `http` URL.

With Bing the following code appears to work:

````
for link in soup.find_all("a", class_="tilk"):
  if link and (link["href"].startswith("https") or link["href"].startswith("http")):
    result_urls.append(link["href"])```
````